# Location of the 'How' regarding RIA Services?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Is there an article / website / book that details the 'How' of WCF RIA Services?  I'm finding it a little questionable that I am relying on a technology that I have really no clue what is going on underneath the hood.  I'm looking for what are the hooks in Visual Studio, why you can't just add a reference to your domain service class from another application and being using it, what are important settings in the .config files, etc.  Is there anything like what I'm looking for?  MSDN was good at illustrating what RIA Services can do, but I'm more interested in the 'How'....kind of like a Don Box sorta explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a decent description, but it might still be more of a 'what' post.

http://nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-Vision-Architecture.aspx

If you crack open a RIA-enabled Silverlight project, you shoule see a LinkedServerProject element.

```
<LinkedServerProject>..\SilverlightApplication.Web\...csproj</LinkedServerProject>
```

That triggers the build targets (Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets) typically installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0" to run the CreateRiaClientFiles task. This task spins up the RIA codegen engine to produce the DomainContexts in the Silverlight project.

A little more information on codegen extensibility can be found in Jeff's post.

http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/10/27/RiaServicesV1SP1Beta.aspx